# now_time is not getting updated while code is looping

Tags: python

i'm trying to do a loop, that keeps checking if time is between 2 times.. so it turns my lights on. but while its looping the current time does not get updated.  im trying to create a aquarium controller, that turns 3 sets of lights on a different times.

thanks for your help :)

```
from  datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()
SleepTimeL = 2

if now_time >= time (9,30) and now_time <= time (16,15):
    print "yes, within the interval"
    print now_time
    time.sleep( 9 )

else:
    print "no"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep updating `now_time` in your loop:

```
while True:
    if time (9,30) <= now_time <= time (16,15):
        print "yes, within the interval"
        now_time = datetime.now().time()
        print now_time
        time.sleep( 9 )
    else:
        print "no"
```

You can replace the conditions with a [*chained comparison*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), which is more readable.

You can also set the comparison as the condition on the `while`, in which case the loop only runs in the specified duration and needs to be restarted for the cycle of the duration:

```
while time (9,30) <= now_time <= time (16,15):
    print "yes, within the interval"
    now_time = datetime.now().time()
    print now_time
    time.sleep( 9 )
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying that but was doing it wrong.. you save me allot of time

Comment: @brandonevans You may consider accepting the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a loop, you should use one, like while.

```
from  datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()
SleepTimeL = 2
print time(19,30)
print now_time
while True:
    if now_time >= time (9,30) and now_time <= time (16,15):
        print "yes, within the interval"
        print now_time
        time.sleep( 9 )
    else: print "no"
```

If you want to make an aquarium controller you should check the lights state in every iteration:

```
from  datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()
SleepTimeL = 2
print time(19,30)
print now_time
while True:
    if now_time >= time (9,30) and now_time <= time (16,15):
        if isLightOff: lightOn 
        time.sleep( 9 )
    else: if isLightOn: lightOff
```